# Is this a Python or SQL server bug?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am running the following: Windows 7, Python 2.5, and SQL server 2005, with SQLNCLI as provider. I have one table, its name is TABLE and its fields are FIELD0, FIELD1, FIELD2.

You can find SQLNCLI.msi here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d09c1d60-a13c-4479-9b91-9e8b9d835cdc&displaylang=en

I'm attemting to use a store procedure. Its purpose is to update a row, or insert it if it doesn't exist. **All goes wrong when it reaches the insert statment, but the insertion succeeds. Here is the code**:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

create procedure [dbo].[TEST0]
    @FIELD0             varchar(200) 
as
begin
    declare @exist varchar(MAX)

    set @exist = (select top 1 [FIELD0] from [TABLE] where [FIELD0] = @FIELD0)

    if @exist is null
    begin
        insert into [TABLE] ([FIELD0],[FIELD1],[FIELD2]) values (@FIELD0,'FIELD1','FIELD2')

        select top 1 [FIELD0] from [TABLE]
        where 
            [FIELD0] = @FIELD0
        return 10
    end
    else
        select top 1 [FIELD0] from [TABLE] where [FIELD0] = @FIELD0 
end
```

To see the bug run this Python code twice; the first time it fails, but the second time it succeeds:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

dbConn = Dispatch( "ADODB.Connection" )
dbConn.Open( "server=xx.xx.xx.xx; initial catalog=MYDB; user=myuser; password=mypass; provider=SQLNCLI" )

command = Dispatch( 'ADODB.Command' )
command.ActiveConnection = s.dbConn
command.CommandText = "[TEST0]"
command.CommandType = 4


param0 = command.CreateParameter ('@FIELD0',200,1,200,'VALUE')
command.Parameters.Append( param0 )
print param0

(rs, result) = command.Execute()
while not rs.EOF:
   dic = {}
   for field in rs.Fields :
      dic[str( field.name )] = str( field.value )
   print dic
rs.MoveNext()
```

Comment: We're not going to install stuff to test your code for you! Please do some more work, narrow down what's going wrong to a small snippet of code, and then post the full error message or lack thereof (what should happen? what did happen? what errors did you get? did you try stepping through in a debugger? what happened then?)

Comment: I have install stuff to test oder users codes =). I solve this already thx

Comment: What's the error message? Does it still happen if you take out the return 10 line in your stored procedure. On a side note: this will fail under high concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

alter procedure [dbo].[TEST0]
    @FIELD0             varchar(200) 
as
begin
    set nocount on <=============================add this
    declare @exist varchar(MAX)

    set @exist = (select top 1 [FIELD0] from [TABLE] where [FIELD0] = @FIELD0)

    if @exist is null
    begin
        insert into [TABLE] ([FIELD0],[FIELD1],[FIELD2]) values (@FIELD0,'FIELD1','FIELD2')

        select top 1 [FIELD0] from [TABLE]
        where 
            [FIELD0] = @FIELD0
    end
    else
        select top 1 [FIELD0] from [TABLE] where [FIELD0] = @FIELD0 
    set nocount off <=============================add this
end
```